# Elasticsearch network.bind_host and network.publish_host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, elasticsearch

I have a 4gb ram machine that works as a DB server for a ios/webapp. On that machine I only have Elasticsearch and MySql installed.

What I want to do now is to only allow connections to ES from two IP addresses. The two servers that hosts the ios and webapp.

Do I set these ip addresses in the ES conf file?:

- `network.host`
- `network.bind_host`
- `network.publish_host`

Answer (score 2):

Those options are to manage what IP will the server use to listen for the incoming connections. I would recommend that you use [Ubuntu firewall](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) to controll who has access to the ES port, or you can use a plugin from Elastic, [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/introduction.html), that provides that feature (as described in [Shield documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/ip-filtering.html).